# Proper way to plot multiple data series in ggplot with custom colors, legend etc

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to incrementally build a plot that contains several data series of different lengths. My goal is to be able to control the appearance of each data series,
give them custom names
 and to have appropriate legends. My data series are of different lengths, so
I cannot put them in a single dataframe.
In the code below I expect 4 lines: the shortest will be red, the next ones will be blue, green and black respectively

```
    library(ggplot2)
    set.seed(12345)
    plt <- ggplot()
    colors <- c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'black')
    for(i in seq(length(colors))) { 
      x <- seq(1, 2*i)
      y <- x * i + rnorm(length(x))
      df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
      plt <- plt +  geom_point(aes(x, y), data=df, color=colors[i]) + 
        geom_line(aes(x, y), data=df, color=colors[i]) 
    }
    print(plt)
```

This is what I get.
[image: my plot]

How can I give names to the lines and display a legend?
Is there a better way to acheive my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to create a single data frame in *long format*:

Like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(12345)
colors <- c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'black')
dat <- lapply(seq_along(colors), function(i){
  x <- seq(1, 2*i)
  data.frame(
    series = colors[i],
    x = x,
    y = x * i + rnorm(length(x))
  )}
)
dat <- do.call(rbind, dat)
```

Now plot

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, color=series)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: nice, but there is a problem: series names (colors) do not match line colors.

Comment: Yes, but does this really matter? I mean, your real labels will probably refer to real things, not the colour of the line? In the event it does matter, you can control this with `scale_colour_manual()` or any of the other colour scales.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use a `for-loop` and plot each time after constructing the data because they are of unequal lengths. This is why `ggplot2` is awesome! You can create a `group` for each of the dataset. And you can name the line to whatever you want using the same `group` as it will appear in the legend as such (of course you can change it directly in the legend as well, later, if you wish). Here's what I think you expect:

```
set.seed(12345)
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)
# to group your data. change the letters to whatever you want to appear as legend
line_names <- letters[1:4]
# Use plyr to create your x and y for each i and add the group.
dat <- ldply(1:length(colors), function(i) {
    x <- seq(1, 2*i)
    y <- x * i + rnorm(length(x))
    data.frame(x=x, y=y, grp=line_names[i])
})

# just plot here.
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line(aes(colour=grp)) + geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot2_multiple_lines]