# How to plot different series with different colors in R?

Tags: r, plot, series

Given the following data:

```
data =

1 2.3
1 3.4
1 2.1
2 4.3
2 5.3
2 6.2
3 0.2
3 0.3
3 0.4
```

I need to plot these data as 3 different series:

- 1st curve: when the 1st column is equal to 1
- 2nd curve: when the 2nd column is equal to 2
- 3rd curve: when the 3rd column is equal to 3

How can I do this in the most flexible way (using different colors)?

Comment: Your question mentions 1st column, 2nd column, 3rd column but your data does not have three columns.  Nor do you mention what you've tried.  Anyway, consider the `ggplot2` package; for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688204/proper-way-to-plot-multiple-data-series-in-ggplot-with-custom-colors-legend-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution I assume that your first column is your grouping variable; the second column the variable that you'd like in the Y-axis. I added a variable x for the time-series.

Data

```
df<-data.frame(v1=as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)), v2=as.numeric(c(2.3, 3.4, 2.1, 4.3, 5.3, 6.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)))

df$x<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
```

ggplot

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x,v2, group=v1, colour=v1)) + geom_line()
```

[image]